# Kibana not displaying any data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

I created visualizations on fly through curl. However, it does not display data.

I have created visualizations by doing as follows
1. Exporting an already built visualization in JSON
2. Modifying the index_name and field names of JSON
3. Importing back the visualization

The visualizations are created in Kibana, they have the same visualization name and refer the index pattern and fields I want. However it does not display any data (graphs)

Can anyone explain what is the problem with the way I am doing ?

Comment: Is the Time Range set appropriately? Have you checked your data in Elasitcsearch? Maybe some filters are on or there is a query in the search field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the variable. I used for find and replacs. The variable I used was also being used to filter data and hence replacing it was not showing any data. My bad